# Backbone.js — url :id not getting passed to where loop

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have this code in my router:

```
category: (id) ->
    alert id
    filteredProducts = new App.Collections.Products(@productsCollection.where({category_id: id}))
    @productsView.renderResults(filteredProducts)
```

The `alert id` call works properly (e.g. app.com/categories/6 > alerts "6") and when I change the `id` in the `where` function to an actual number the products collection filters properly like so:

```
filteredProducts = new App.Collections.Products(@productsCollection.where({designer_id: 6}))
```

But when I set the `designer_id: id` the where loop return an empty collection.

Comment: Could it be that you're calling `Altar.Collections.Pieces` in the second one, but `App.Collections.Pieces` in the first?

Comment: no that's not it. My App is named Altar but to reduce confusion about what Altar is I renamed it to App in my post, but forgot to change it in the second call. My bad! Changed the original post to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My foreign key category_id was a number not a string. The answer is:

```
filteredProducts = new App.Collections.Products(@productsCollection.where({category_id: parseInt(id)}))
```